# Microsoft Outlook - Automatically trigger mail to a particular user if 'n' number of mails comes in 5 mins interval

Tags: email, outlook, ms-office

I am in a situation where i have to count the number of mails of a particular subject daily and if it matches the particular count then i have to mail to a person. can this be automated with outlook rules ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a rule and assign a VBA macro to it. The VBA macro should look the following one:

```
Public Sub Test(mail as MailItem)
  '
End Sub
```

In the VBA macro you can check out the subject, increase the counter for incoming emails and start the timer. In the subsequent calls you can check out the elapsed time and counter (how many items were recieved) and then run any additional actions if required. See [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) for more information.